# File Get Contents not returning result

Tags: php

I have the following code, which sends an ip address to a page on another server, which then processes the ip address and returns the description.

The problem being is that i get no errors, but the code does not return the results.

The code to send the IP address

```
 $response = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/bean/ripe.php?ip=$ip');
 print_r( $response );
```

The code to get the ip address, process it and return the result.

```
 if ( isset( $_GET['ip'] ) && $_GET['ip'] ) {

    include("ipology.class.php");
$ipology = new ipology( array($ip) );
$out = $ipology->out();
foreach( $out as $ip ) {
if( is_array( $ip ) ) {

$address = implode( ", ", (array) 
                $ip['address'] );
                $descr   = implode( ", ", (array) $ip['descr'] );
               echo "$descr";   

} }}
```

Comment: Sorry what do you mean,

Comment: Check that you have set the ini config value `allow_url_fopen` to true in order to allow URLs to be read using file_get_contents.

Comment: Thanks the setting is set to on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently not passing an IP address to the URL, you are passing the literal `$ip_address`. This is because you are using single quotes `'` for the url. Use double quotes `"` if you want to pass variables to a string:

```
$response = file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/bean/ripe.php?ip=$ip_address");
```

Comment: Thanks, Still not getting a response, i think i will have to wait until tomorrow and get the hosting company to check the ini file settings.

Comment: you can check yourself using `phpinfo()`

Comment: i changed the isset on the outbound page and it worked, after adding your changes, thank you for your help, really appreciated